# Hibernate could not find table when hibernate.hb2ddl.auto=validate and hibernate.default_schema=xyz in SQL Server

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application that has access to multiple datasources, hence I have programmatically created datasources for each of the DB.

My database is on SQL Server

I have also injected LocationContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for each of these datasources.

In the EntityManager I have included the following JPA properties

### hibernate.hb2ddl.auto=validate

### hibernate.default_schema=xyz

Though my entity exists in the db and in the schema xyz, Hibernate throws a Schema Management Exception that the table abc was not found.

If I remove the hibernate.hb2ddl.auto=validate property, hibernate is able to identify the table.

Anyone has come across this issue earlier ?
Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what we figured out.

JPA also has an additional property that needs to be set if you are working with SQL Server and schema separation.

`jpa.properties.hibernate.default_catalog=<your_db_catalog>`

This property needs to be set and your schema separation should work fine.

Hope the answer helps someone in the future.